# button click get parent's text value in each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
function myFun(ele){
    ele.each(function(){        
        var org = $(this).text();
        $(document).delegate('.c','click',function(){
            $(this).parent().append(org);
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    myFun($('.text'));
});
</script>
<p class="text">12345678910<span class="c"> +</span></p>
<p class="text">abcdefghijklmnopq<span class="c"> +</span></p>
```

I have a testing function, when '+' button click, it will append the parent text.

ex. if i click 1st one, it should append 123...

if i click 2nd one should append abc...

what happen now is this append everything 123... abc...

how to just append the parent's text only

Comment: Why are you using `$(document).delegate('.c','click',function(){` in each?

Comment: you need to bind event only once..that should be out of your `.each` loop

Comment: the reason i use delegate, because im going to use jquery load another page into it, i will need this function works for another page too

Comment: Did you want to include the `<span class="c"> +</span>` when the parent's text is appended? Where did you want the appended text to be, after the span tag and before the closing paragraph tag? And what should happen when you click multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$('.c').click(function () {
    $(this).append($(this).parent().text());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNvp6/)

Note, with the current way you are doing the binding, you are actually binding two events to each .c class. You are looping through all .text classes, and binding to .c. Because there are two, you get two binding, two handlers, and two executions on click.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4chV6djtvAjjzCoeufvW?p=preview) is the jsfiddle updated.

```
function myFun(ele){
  $(document).delegate('.c','click',function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();

    parent.append(parent.text());
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    myFun($('.text'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's assuming you only want the text copied and not the child `span`

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/JEL8F/)

```
$(".text").on("click", ".c", function () {
    var parentText = $(this).parent(".text").clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
    $(this).prepend(parentText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that for each ".text" you are calling "$(document).delegate('.c','click',..." twice (for each ".c") which results in two click handlers attached to each ".c"

To correct this you need to attach the click handler to only the ".c" in the current ".text" using the find function like this:

```
function myFun(ele){
    ele.each(function(){        
        var org = $(this).text();
        $(this).find('.c').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().append(org);
        });
    });
 }
```